# How to rebind a key to "Continue" command other than F5 in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, intellij-idea, ide, key-bindings

In Visual Studio, <kbd>F5</kbd> is used for both of **StartDebugging** and **Continue**, which is rather annoying. Because many other IDEs/Debuggers don't act in the same way, e.g. **cgdb**, **IntelliJ IDEA**.

For simplicity and universality, I want to use one key-binding scheme for all IDEs/Debuggers. I cannot change other IDEs/Debuggers to bind both of **StartDebugging** and **Continue** to <kbd>F5</kbd>.

So, my question is:

Is there a way to separately bind **StartDebugging** and **Continue** to different keys in Visual Studio?

Comment: I created a support ticket at visual studio. Please upvote it to make it happen:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/665439/keyboard-shortcut-for-debugcontinue.html

Answer (score 13):

The command you're looking to change is called `Debug.Start`

This link describes how you can remap commands to different keys:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5zwses53.aspx

`Debug.Start` is the same command for both **Run** and **Continue**, so you cannot map the action to different keys.

Comment: No it won't allow you to bind to different keys, that's exactly what he was asking, as I have the same problem, Run and Continue are bound to the same command.

Comment: Yeah this sucks, it doesn't match other comon debuggers (chrome, intellij, or even visual studio code), would be nice to have to get standardized keys.

Comment: I created a support ticket to change it to run and continue at visual studio. Please upvote it to make it happen:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/665439/keyboard-shortcut-for-debugcontinue.html

Comment: I've voted on that I suggest everyone else do the same!

Comment: You can map multiple keys to the same command.  I have both F5 and F8 bound to `Debug.Start`.  It's not identical behavior to other IDEs but practically the same in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround that I use is to have two shortcuts bound to `Debug.Start`. This way it allows me to naturally use the keybinds I'm used to when debugging -- for me that's pressing F9 to continue:

[image]

You'll notice there are now two shortcuts bound to `Debug.Start`:
[image]

so you can still use F5 to start debugging and then your chosen key to `Debug.Continue` when you're debugging.